# Simple HTML page help/guuide required

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am totally new in HTML and not having much idea how to work with HTML tag so that I am posting a question to get some help/guidance from the HTML programmers. Please kindly help me.

Question :- I want to design the same as attached and the code below is not giving me the correct output. Everything is here and there and not able to align it properly.

The main issue is formatting and placing of content. I tried to align it with float but it didn't worked for me so I removed it.

LINK - http://jsfiddle.net/d7VNu/

```
<html>
<head></head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta charset="utf-8">

<body>
<table width="500px" height="800px">
<tr style="color:#cc0000"><td>Customer Information</td></tr>
<tr height="30px" style="font-size=10px;" ><td>Name on Order:</td> <td>Ben Berlin</td></tr>
<tr height="30px" style="font-size=10px;"><td>Delivery Address:</td> <td>724 West Aldine Avenue Chicago, IL 60657 </td></tr>
<tr height="30px" style="font-size=10px;"><td>Callback Phone #: </td> <td>248-561-9708</td></tr>
<tr height="30px" style="font-size=10px;"><td>Your [1]Store:</td> <td>2921 N Clark St, Chicago, IL 60657 | 773-549-3328 </td></tr>
<tr height="30px" style="font-size=10px;"><td>Delivery Time:</td><td>Under an hour</td></tr>

<br/>

<tr style="color:#cc0000"><td>Order Details</td></tr>
<tr style="font-size=10px;"><td>Order #:</td> <td>56760620</td></tr>
<tr style="font-size=10px;"><td>Date:</td> <td>03/27/2014 11:03AM</td></tr>

<br/>

<tr><td>Quantity</td> <td>Description</td><td>Amount</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td> <td>Portobello Benedict</td><td>$15</td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td> <td>Iced Latte</td><td>$8</td></tr>

<br/>
<br/>
<tr><td>Subtotal:</td> <td>$23</td></tr>
<tr><td>Discount:</td> <td>-$2.50</td></tr>
<tr><td>Delivery Charges:</td> <td>$0.00</td></tr>
<tr><td>Tip:</td> <td>$3.07</td></tr>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Place your code in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for us t view and edit please

Comment: I don't know why people start down voting. Instead they can comment that what is wrong in the question. I mentioned clearly that I am new and I need help/guidance. I am not asking anyone for spoon fiding.

Comment: You were downvoted because your question didn't have a question (before you edited in the second paragraph).

Comment: as you can see there is some people they think they are too good to give their time for beginners, anyways do what @LcLk told you. Then we can help you

Comment: @JefferyThaGintoki, I have added link in my question.

Comment: @JefferyThaGintoki You couldn't be more wrong. Some people (myself included) do not have _time_ to guess at what people might be asking. We have finite time to provide to this site, and don't want to waste it on ambiguous requests. It has nothing to do with anyone thinking they are 'better' than anyone else.

Comment: @JefferyThaGintoki, sorry if I was wrong in putting it properly but I will surely try to make it more constructive and precise before posting it in future. Thank you..

Comment: @Clive well bro, i said there is some people, did i included everyone in my opinion? and also before downrating a question try to help the asker, else you move away and not downrating, what it did to you to downrating the question? tell him where he commits the mistake so he won't do it again else don't just downrate it and go away.

Comment: @JefferyThaGintoki No, you implied that there's an undertone of elitism here, and that elitism is somehow responsible for the OP's question being badly received. Which is, of course, absolute nonsense. So I called you on it, and as you can see, others agree. Like I said, I have finite amount of time here. It's not my, nor anyone else here's, job to hold the hand of a 1K+, or any other, user through how to ask a coherent question. By refusing to downvote poor content, you are actively helping to make this site a worse place. Congrats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here check your HTML: [Order List](http://jsfiddle.net/d7VNu/4/)

and also for this two tags:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

you can use one of these, the first one is generally used in HTML 4, and the other one is used in HTML 5.
One other thing is to never use the style attribute in your tags try to learn more about CSS and stylesheet files [CSS Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/css/DEFAULT.asp), because instead of using the same style everytime in each tag you can use one extern file with your style and can be applicable to all your concerned tags by adding `CLASS` or `ID` to your tag.

GoodLuck bro.

Answer (score 1):

use this code

your table structure was not correct

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta charset="utf-8">

<body>
<table width="500px" height="800px">
  <tr style="color:#cc0000">
    <td width="126">Customer Information</td>
    <td width="271">  </td><td width="87">&nbsp;  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr height="30px" style="font-size=10px;" >
    <td>Name on Order:</td>
    <td>Ben Berlin</td><td>&nbsp;  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr height="30px" style="font-size=10px;">
    <td>Delivery Address:</td>
    <td>724 West Aldine Avenue Chicago, IL 60657 </td><td>&nbsp;  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr height="30px" style="font-size=10px;">
    <td>Callback Phone #: </td>
    <td>248-561-9708</td><td>&nbsp;  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr height="30px" style="font-size=10px;">
    <td>Your [1]Store:</td>
    <td>2921 N Clark St, Chicago, IL 60657 | 773-549-3328 </td><td>&nbsp;  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr height="30px" style="font-size=10px;">
    <td>Delivery Time:</td>
    <td>Under an hour</td><td>&nbsp;  </td>
  </tr>
  <br/>
  <tr style="color:#cc0000">
    <td>Order Details</td>
    <td>&nbsp;  </td><td>&nbsp;  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="font-size=10px;">
    <td>Order #:</td>
    <td>56760620</td><td>&nbsp;  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="font-size=10px;">
    <td>Date:</td>
    <td>03/27/2014 11:03AM</td><td>&nbsp;  </td>
  </tr>
  <br/>
  <tr>
    <td>Quantity</td>
    <td>Description</td>
    <td align="right"><strong>Amount</strong></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Portobello Benedict</td>
    <td align="right"> <font color="#FF0000"> $15</font></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Iced Latte</td>
    <td align="right"> <font color="#FF0000">$8</font></td>
  </tr>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <tr>
    <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="right"><strong>Subtotal:</strong></td>
    <td align="right">$23</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="right"><strong>Discount:</strong></td>
    <td align="right">-$2.50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="right"><strong>Delivery Charges:</strong></td>
    <td align="right">$0.00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="right"><strong>Tip:</strong></td>
    <td align="right">$3.07</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="right"> <font color="#FF0000" size="+2">Total</font></td>
    <td align="right"><font color="#FF0000" size="+2">$12.15</font></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3"> <font color="#00CCCC"  size="+1">payment detail:</font><br>
bla bala bla bala bala, bla bala bla bala bala, bla bala bla bala bala<br>
bla bala bla bala  bla bala bala, bla bala bla bala bala</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

some missed add ( td )